# Can you help me to identify following elements React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, element

Can you help me to identify following elements in next image? [image]

- 1) First element are tabnavigator?
- 2) "Post" elements are a FlatList,SectionList ?
- 3) The last element are a bottomTabNavigator?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: This is not a technical question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, 1 and 3 are not built-in react components, so they are originated either in custom components created for this project, or in open source projects. 
 
That being said, as far as terminology goes: 

1.Appears to be a tab navigator. 
2.Could be a FlatList or just a ScrollView 
3.Bottom navigation. Should be navigating between screens rather than tabs, at least as far as good design goes.